# Android studio Currency converter coding

Tags: android, currency, converters

I'm trying to make currency converter app in android studio,but i can't start my app in emulator and i believe it is because some errors in coding.I will copy my code here so you can help me ,I would be grateful.Sorry for my bad English :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     public void clickFunction(View view) {
        Log.i ("Info", "Button pressed");
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(editText);
        Log.i(       "Values" ,editText,getText().toString());
        String amountInEuros = editText.getText()
                Log.i("Info" , String.valueOf(editText.getText()));
        String getAmountInEuros ;
        double  amountInEuros  double  = double.parsedouble (amountInEuros);
        double  amountInDollars double = double amountInEuros double * 1.08 ;
        String amountInDollars String = double.toString (amountInDollars double)
        Log.i("Amount in Dollars", amountInDollars String);
        Toast.makeText ( this ,  amountInEuros + "Euros" + "is" + amountInDollars String , LENGTH_LONG );
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Provide the error you get inside Logcat.

Comment: I get error ";" expected, <identifier> expected but i dont know what to do with those errors

Answer (score 0):

These lines are missing a semicolon :

```
String amountInEuros = editText.getText();

String amountInDollars String = double.toString (amountInDollars double);
```